# Does Steam Controller work on Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: games, steam

I would like to update my current setup to a gaming rig and continue to use Ubuntu. Is Ubuntu 19.x compatible with the Steam Controller?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I run it with the 3rd party software [SC-Controller](https://github.com/kozec/sc-controller), which is an alternative if one wants no steam software on their system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, so long as you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install steam-devices` to update then install Steam Devices.